# Cannot save POST items to database with Phalcon framework

Tags: php, html, phalcon

**Controller:**

```
class PeopleController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller{

public function indexAction(){

}
public function CreatePersonAction(){
        $person = new people();
        $person->firstName=$this->request->getPost("firstName");                
        $person->surname=$this->request->getPost("surname");
        $person->telephone=$this->request->getPost("telephone");
        $person->email=$this->request->getPost("email");
        $person->city=$this->request->getPost("city");
        $person->country=$this->request->getPost("country");
        $person->save();
    if ($person) {
        echo"Successfully Registered User!";


    } else {
        echo "Sorry, the following problems were generated: ";
        foreach ($person->getMessages() as $message) {
            echo $message->getMessage(), "<br/>";
        }
    }


    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
<?php

class People extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model{


}
```

I have tried implementing the getSource() method into the model as the phalcon docs suggest that but still not getting the desired output of saving the POST items to the database

Comment: Is your DB field names are like `firstName`, `surname`, ... ?

Comment: From the docu: _If you’re using PHP 5.4/5.5 it is recommended you declare each column that makes part of the model in order to save memory and reduce the memory allocation._ (Just a hint, not the solution to your problem)

Comment: `getSource()` is only neccessary if you table is not named _people_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller as PhController;

class PeopleController extends PhController
{
    public function IndexAction()
    {
        //When no view(aka template) is used you should disable the view rendering
        //Otherwise the output buffer can get overwritten and your echoes won't display
        $this->view->disable(); 

        echo "<h1>Index Action!</h1>";
    }

    public function CreatePersonAction()
    {
        $this->view->disable();

        if($this->request->isPost()) {
            $dataSent = $this->request->getPost();

            $person = new People();
            $person->firstName  = $dataSent["firstName"]
            $person->surname    = $dataSent["surname"];
            $person->telephone  = $dataSent["telephone"];
            $person->email      = $dataSent["email"];
            $person->city       = $dataSent["city"];
            $person->country    = $dataSent["country"];

            $savedSuccessfully = $person->save();

            if($savedSuccessfully) {
                echo "Successfully Registered User!";
            } else {
                $messages = $person->getMessages();

                echo "Sorry, the following problems were generated: ";
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    echo "$message <br/>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "The request method should be POST!";  
        }
    }
}
```

Also, add this code to your main **index.php** (just before `Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()`):

```
$debug = new \Phalcon\Debug();
$debug->listen();
```

With this you'll get better error messages, so you can check if your DB settings are OK. Also remember that Phalcon only works with the database schema passively, that means, all tables and fields should already exist to the Model get stored, Phalcon just **use** the tables and **never create them**.

Comment: Ohk this seems to get me closer to where i need to be as it is complaining the request is not post..Is there possibly something wrong with my HTML in the views. I have the following:                  `<form method="POST" action="createPerson">                                                          <div class="input-group">
  <label for="firstName">First Name</label><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName">`

Comment: @JoshBoiskin please send me all your HTML in a [**pastebin**](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @JoshBoiskin with all respect you need to learn some HTML basics first before diving into PHP. Try to fix your HTML first.

Comment: Ohk Thank you , now atleast i know that there is a problem with my HTML , have a nice day